# A user guide to the theory on Corks

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, surgery-theory

I am trying to digest the meanings of the corks from the both:

- algebraic topology

and

- geometry topology

perspectives.

Studying corks is important for understanding the exotic phenomenon of 4-manifolds. A definition of cork can be (a
generalized form):

> **Definition (Cork)**:

Let $C$ be a contractible 4-manifold and $t$ a self-diffeomorphism $∂C → ∂C$ on the boundary. If $t$ **cannot** extend to a map $C → C$ as a diffeomorphism, then $(C, t)$ is called a cork.

> **Definition (Cork twist)**:

For a pair of exotic two 4-manifolds $M1$, $M2$ and a smooth embedding $C ֒→ M1$, if $M1(C, t) = M2$, then $(C, t)$ is called a cork for $M1$, $M2$. We call
the deformation $M1 → M1(C, t)$ a cork twist.

This definition seems to be weaker than the usual Stein cork.

> **Definition (Stein twist)**:

I think the Stein cork follows that --- $C$ is Stein and $t$ satisfies $t^2 =$ id. If the 4-manifold $C$ of a cork $(C, t)$ is Stein, then $(C, t)$ is called a Stein cork.

> My question:
>
> (1) The above may be from a more geometry topology viewpoint. Do we have similar definitions from a more? algebraic topology viewpoint
>
> (2) What are the intuitions and the background motivations to define the
>
> - Cork
> - Cork twist
> - Stein Cork
>
> in the above ways? Why is that a helpful idea?
>
> (**Bonus**: Are these only useful in **4-manifolds**? Or also suitable for **other dimensional manifolds**?)

Comment: some of Akubulut's earlier papers has very nice intuition. It's all about how you attach a cancelling 1-2 pair where you are now  attaching the 2 handle along some attaching circle which is homotopic(not isotopic) to the original one. Key word: positve whitehead multiple of a knot.